# Unable to correct the error " Fail 1 - Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on my programming assignment, which is described as follows!

Create a web page which calculates the discount for the product for the specific season. The seasons with their discount rates are summer (10%), new year (5%) and clearance (15%). The discount is calculated on the price of the product.

Expected I/P, O/P are shared in the below links:
Input Screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnqgq.jpg
Output Screen 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dau2.png
Requirements for the webpage are as follows :

Web page Requirements

The web page background color should be #99FFFF. The label “Discount Price” should be a heading tag(h1) and should be italic bolded, centered, and in color code #b03060.

Product name - a text box with the name "name", should not be empty, contain only alphabets and space and mandatory field.

Price - a number box with the name price, mandatory field and the minimum value should be greater than 15000.

Season is a drop down box with tag name “season”. The drop down box will have the following value and display value

·         summer           -           SUMMER SALE

·         newyear          -           NEW YEAR SALE

·         clearance        -           CLEARANCE SALE

The table should be left aligned with 35% and an outer border style of solid 5px and 30% border width. The space between element and the border must be 10px.

A submit button with left aligned with 45% and with a value “GET DISCOUNT PRICE” should be present. Once submit, the web page calculates the discounted price for the product.

The outcome must be displayed in 2 div tags, where the first will have the id named “discount” and is to display the discount % of the product and the second will have the id named “result” and is to display the discounted price of the product. Both the div tags should be center aligned with bold text. The font of the discounted price must be italic, #FF0000 and 40px size and for discount % it is 25px. Have separate styles for div, discount and result.

I am getting the error :
`Fail 1 - Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr`

My code snippet is as follows, can anyone help me with the error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body 
            {
                background-color: #99FFFF;
            }
            h1{
                font-style:italic;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
                color: Maroon;
            }
            table{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                text-align: center;
                border : 5px solid black;
                width: 30%;
                margin-left: 35%;
            }
            tr,td
            {
                text-align: left;
                padding: 10px;
                border: solid 2px black;
            }
            #submitbutton
            {
              margin-left: 45%;   
            }
            div{
                text-align:center;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #result{
                font-style:italic;
                color:#FF0000;
                font-size:40px;
            }
            #discount{
                font-size:25px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function discount()
            {
                    var x = document.myForm.season.value;
                    var disc;
                    if(x.match("summer"))
                    {
                        disc = 10;
                    }
                    else if(x.match("newyear"))
                    {
                        disc = 5;
                    }
                    else if(x.match("clearance"))
                    {
                        disc = 15;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "The discount is "+disc+"%";
                    var p = document.myForm.price.value;
                    p = p - (p*disc)/100;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The discounted price : Rs "+p;
                    return false;

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>DISCOUNT PRICE</h1>
        <form method="get" name="myForm" onsubmit="return discount()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" required pattern="[\sa-zA-Z]+"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Price</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" required pattern="[\d]+" min="15001"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Season</td>
                    <td><select name="season" id="season">
                        <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
                        <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
                        <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id = "submitbutton" value="GET DISCOUNT PRICE">
        </form>
        <br/>
        <div id="discount"></div>
        <br/>
        <div id="result"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the validator expecting a tbody tag?

Comment: what's with the `...solid 5px and 30% border width.`? It is either 5px or 30%, can't have both.

Comment: @epascarello No, the validator isn't!

Comment: @RenevanderLende It is mentioned in the problem statement, so how should I go about it?

Comment: As with any IT question, ask the one who gave the assignment. "user: Hey the screen is pink", "you: Yeah, you said pink", "user: Ok, but I meant lavender". To me that part of your assignment looks mutual exclusive, you need more input from the assigner... Choosing yourself would be guessing, and you know about that, most of the time you will be wrong.

Comment: Could be on purpose, to see if you get back and inquire about it. That would be the CSS part. For the other error, I see three table rows, so "what's up, validator??"

Comment: Furthermore, provided you posted the exact assignment text, there is no explicit specification that says that 3 table rows is mandatory. Implied by 'product', 'price' and 'season', true, but even if you inserted 50 blank rows that should not be a fail (as per spec.), only sloppy... On account of inserting `<tbody>` or not: inserting would be proper syntax/semantics. Leaving it out (although it is allowed and widely accepted) is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming the text you posted exactly matches the assignment text**

I have analyzed your assignment and your code and found just a few discrepancies. Actually, the assignment specifications where not complete, leaving room for personal interpretation.

First off

- you have 3 table rows, so I don't understand the error on that.

Secondly

- `h1 {...color: #b03060...}` as per spec, not `Maroon`
- `table {...text-align: center...}` not spec
- `table {...border-collapse: collapse...}` not spec, but implied by the images.
- `tr,td {...text-align: left...}` not spec. Also, `text-align` is `left` by default, hense redundant.

Specification omissions:

- use of `<form>` (spec says 'webpage' not 'form', big difference! The used `<h1>` and `<div>` are `<form>` dependend, not webpage dependend).
- consequently form `name` omitted
- position of `<h1>` inside `<form>` (part of form not webpage, assume modal use)
- position of `<div>` inside `<from>` (ditto)
- number of table rows to use
- Use of javascript (implied, but not spec)
- Name of JS function

Below my code snippet fully commented with my findings (copied your javascript as-is, not analyzed)...

```js
            function discount()
            {
                    var x = document.myForm.season.value;
                    var disc;
                    if(x.match("summer"))
                    {
                        disc = 10;
                    }
                    else if(x.match("newyear"))
                    {
                        disc = 5;
                    }
                    else if(x.match("clearance"))
                    {
                        disc = 15;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML = "The discount is "+disc+"%";
                    var p = document.myForm.price.value;
                    p = p - (p*disc)/100;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The discounted price : Rs "+p;
                    return false;

            }
```

```css
            /* The web page background color should be #99FFFF */
            body {
                background-color: #99FFFF; /* spec */
            }
            /* The label “Discount Price” should be a 
                  - heading tag(h1) and should be 
                  - italic
                  - bolded,
                  - centered, and in 
                  - color code #b03060. */
            h1 {
                font-style : italic;  /* spec */
                font-weight: bold;    /* spec */
                text-align : center;  /* spec */
                color      : #b03060; /* mod, was 'Maroon' not spec */
            }
            /* Use of <form> not specified, implied */

            /*
                The table should be 
                   - left aligned with 35% and an 
                   - outer border style of solid 5px
                   - and 30% border width. (?????)
            */
            /* Ambiguous spec: outer border style of solid 5px and 30% border width */
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;  /* not spec, implied from img */
            /*    text-align     : center;    /* !!!!!!!not spec */
                border         : 5px solid; /* spec */
                margin-left    : 35%;       /* spec */
            }
            /* 
                The space between element and the border must be 10px
                (!!!!!!!maximum row count not in spec!!!!!!!) */
            tr,td {
            /*    text-align: left; /* !!!!!!!not spec, but left alignment is default html */
                padding   : 10px; /* spec */
                border    : solid 2px black; /* not spec, implied from img */
            }
            /*
                Use of <br> between table, button and div is implied from img,
                no type of spacing between these elements is specified.
            */

            /*
                A submit button with 
                   - left aligned with 45% and
                   - with a value “GET DISCOUNT PRICE” should be present.
            */
            #submitbutton {
              margin-left: 45%; /* spec */
            }
            /*
            The outcome must be displayed in 2 div tags,

            where the first will have the
               - id named “discount” and is to 
               - display the discount % of the product
            
            and the second will have the 
               - id named “result” and is to
               - display the discounted price of the product.
            
            Both the div tags should be 
               center aligned with bold text.
               
            The font of the discounted price must be
               - italic,
               - #FF0000 and 
               - 40px size
            
             and for discount % it is
               - 25px.
            
            Have separate styles for div, discount and result.

            (Below CSS up to spec)
            */

            /* Separate styles as per spec */
            div {
                text-align : center; /* spec */
                font-weight: bold;   /* spec */
            }
            #discount {
                font-size: 25px; /* spec */
            }
            #result {
                font-style: italic;  /* spec */
                color     : #FF0000; /* spec */
                font-size : 40px;    /* spec */
            }
```

```html
        <!-- should probably be part of <form>, but not in spec as such -->
        <h1>DISCOUNT PRICE</h1>

        <!-- Use of form implied, not in spec, name not in spec -->
        <form method="get" name="myForm" onsubmit="return discount()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <!-- ROW 1 (up to spec)
                     Product name - a text box with the name "name",
                        - should not be empty,
                        - contain only alphabets and
                        - space and mandatory field.
    
                    -->
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" required pattern="[\sa-zA-Z]+"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <!-- ROW 2 (up to spec)
                    Price 
                       - a number box 
                       - with the name price,
                       - mandatory field and 
                       - the minimum value should be greater than 15000.
                     -->
                    <td>Product Price</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" required pattern="[\d]+" min="15001"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <!-- ROW 3 (up to spec)
                    Season 
                       - is a drop down box 
                       - with tag name “season”.
                    
                       - The drop down box will have the following value and display value
                         · summer - SUMMER SALE
                         · newyear - NEW YEAR SALE
                        · clearance - CLEARANCE SALE
                     -->
                    <td>Season</td>
                    <td><select name="season" id="season">
                        <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
                        <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
                        <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <!-- spec -->
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id = "submitbutton" value="GET DISCOUNT PRICE">
        </form>

        <!-- should probably be part of <form>, but not in spec as such -->
        <br/>
        <div id="discount"></div>
        <br/>
        <div id="result"></div>
```